# C# GetBytes, WriteBytes and Embedded Statement Error

Tags: c#, stream, byte

I have a  problem. When I run my program, it comes up with an error, specifically the CS1023 error. I guess it's because I have a declaration inside a statement, but I don't know how else to write the code. Sometimes C# annoys me, because in C++ I could get away with similar things... anyway, here's the code. I would appreciate it if somebody could explain it to me. 
[Error Message Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xaw06638(VS.80).aspx)

```
void BtnTotalSeasonsClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream(drvFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) 
    Byte[] bytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(txtTotalSeasons.Text);
    {
        stream.Position = 4;
        Stream.WriteByte(0xCD);
    }
}
```

Fixed Code with CS0120 error.

```
        {
using (var stream = new FileStream(drvFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))  
{ 
Byte[] bytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(txtTotalSeasons.Text); 
stream.Position = 4; 
Stream.WriteByte(0xCD); 
} 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>There's nothing apparently wrong with the code you pasted in. Perhaps the error is somewhere else above this, and the compiler is getting confused?</strike>

Ah, I see you've changed the code.

The problem here is you are declaring the `Byte[]` array outside the *intended* `using` block. Since the scope of the declaration as is is only one line, this constitutes a logic error, and the compiler catches it with a compile-time error.

The compiler is interpreting your code like this:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(drvFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))  
{ 
    Byte[] bytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(txtTotalSeasons.Text); 
}

{        
    stream.Position = 4; 
    stream.WriteByte(0xCD); 
}
```

To fix it, move the `Byte[]` inside the braces, or outside the `using` block:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(drvFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))  
{ 
    Byte[] bytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(txtTotalSeasons.Text); 
    stream.Position = 4; 
    stream.WriteByte(0xCD); 
}
```

-or-

```
Byte[] bytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(txtTotalSeasons.Text); 

using (var stream = new FileStream(drvFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))  
{ 
    stream.Position = 4; 
    stream.WriteByte(0xCD); 
}
```

Personally, I like being annoyed by the compiler here, since it saves me from a run-time error.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Now another error (CS0120) has come up, so I'll fix that. Thanks though.

Comment: Instance method call needs an instance? We can help with that, here, too!

Comment: Well, could you help with that also? I get two errors, one in the 4th. line of code above, and one in the 6th, both being CS0120 errors.

Comment: "Stream.WriteByte(0xCD);" - needs to be "stream.WriteByte(0xCD);" C# is case sensitive, and "Stream" refers to the class, not the object, which is "stream".